# Getting issue while trying to run the protractor in centos docker image: chrome failed to start

Tags: docker, selenium, centos, protractor, xvfb

I am trying to run the selenium test cases in a docker container with Centos using a protractor. I am getting an error. Even I have the latest version of the xvfb package.

[image]

Comment: how do you run your tests. Attach the code

Comment: Using Protractor